# How I can write this code shorter ? without "if"

Tags: c

I dont want use "if", i want change it to something short, how i can make it without "if" ?

```
int a,b,c;
scanf ("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);

if (a%2!=0)
    printf("%d ",a);
if (b%2!=0)
    printf("%d ",b);    
if (c%2!=0)
    printf("%d ",c);
```

Comment: This is short enough. What most you can do is to create a function and call it in a loop, instead of copying same line of code for check and print.

Comment: You have logical conditions. You *need* an `if` or something that's basically an `if` even if not technically an if. Don't play games. State your conditions clearly.

Comment: Tip: Use a function, save data in an array. Use an iterator value.

Comment: You could use the `?` `:` operator, but that just makes the code less readable: `a%2 ? printf("%d ", a) : 0;`. Or use `&&`: `a%2 && printf("%d ", a);`.

Comment: Replace the absence of a number with `0`? `printf("%d %d %d\n", a * (a % 2), b * (b % 2), c * (c % 2));`

Comment: how to make a loop ?, can u give example

Comment: @tadman Logical conditions can often be replaced by arithmetics. And this one could be as well, it just wouldn't make a lot of sense here.

Comment: @TEXNO You think this code is not short enough, you don't want to use `if`, but you don't even know how to make a loop? Get your priorities straight. If you don't want to write code, don't program.

Comment: Why? You are using stdio.h. That's 99.9% of the performance bottleneck in this program. So what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @EmanuelP I'm not sure how you can "mathematically" not print something.

Comment: @tadman I'm pretty sure you would understand how `puts(str+i)` would not print something based on the value of `i`.

Comment: @EmanuelP Oh, sure, if you want to get downright obfuscated you could do `char* lol[] = { "", "%d " }` and then `printf(lol[c%2], n)` but that's how you get banned from making commits to a project and uninvited from all the cool parties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to avoid if statements you could use ternary operator (which is an if statement in disguise) like this:

```c
a & 1 ? printf("%d ", a) : 0;
b & 1 ? printf("%d ", b) : 0;
c & 1 ? printf("%d ", c) : 0;
```

I would not suggest doing this as it is very ugly solution. Instead of having multiple ifs statements it would be a lot cleaner to use array with a loop like so:

```c
int arr[3];

scanf("%d %d %d", &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2]);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    if (arr[i] & 1) printf("%d ", arr[i]);
```

Comment: This is likely going to result in pretty much the same machine code though, with the same branching. So it's just obfuscation for nothing gained.

Comment: The second form is great and could be improved by making the `3` a `const int` defined in advance, making it very flexible. The first form is a total mess and would hard-fail most code reviews.

Comment: in one line    `a & 1 ? printf("%d ", a) : b & 1 ? printf("%d ", b) : c & 1 ? printf("%d ", c) : 0;`

Comment: @0___________ Wrong site, you are looking for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: And notably, any modern compiler can optimize `a%2 != 1` into the same machine code as `a & 1`.

Comment: I forgot :) at the end

Comment: @0___________ If you don't count includes and macros any C code can be written in one line... doesn't mean it should.

Comment: @0___________ your code implemens 2 extra `else` that aren't there.

Answer (score 3):

Even if I can't see a reason for it, if you really want, you can do it without any if or conditional operator like this:

```
char *f[] = { "", "%d " };
printf(f[a & 1], a);
printf(f[b & 1], b);
printf(f[c & 1], c);
```

More important, check the return value of `scanf()`, and provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a,b,c;
    if (scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c) == 3) {
        char *f[] = { "", "%d " };
        printf(f[a & 1], a);
        printf(f[b & 1], b);
        printf(f[c & 1], c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test it [here](https://ideone.com/6ncIlv).